# Filemaker: Portal with Multiple fields from multiple tables

Tags: sorting, field, filemaker

I want to display multiple fields from different table on a portal.

Table1: Primary Key ID_patient

Table2: Primary Key ID_aneurysm Foreign Key ID_patient

Table3: Primary Key ID_Imaging Foreign Key ID_aneurysm

*Table1(Patient)-->Table2(Aneurysm)-->Table3(Image)*

**I create a portal in the layout ID_patient. I sort the portal by ID_aneurysm. I then place the fields I need.**

I expect this kind of result:

ID_aneurysm1 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1 image1

IDaneurysm1 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging2 dateofimaging2 image2

IDaneurysm2 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1

**But the second ID_imaging2 and the records linked to it do not appear...
I had this kind only:**

IDaneurysm1 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1 image1

IDaneurysm2 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1 image1

**The portal do not display the ID_imaging 2 from ID_aneurusysm1**

**I tried to sort it by ID_imaging and I have**

ID_aneurysm1 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1 image1

IDaneurysm1 dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging2 dateofimaging2 image2

**IDaneurysm1** dateofdiscovery1 ID_imaging1 dateofimaging1

**All the data are displayed but the data related to the table ID_aneurysm are the all ID_aneurysm1 and not ID_aneurysm2 and so on...**

Here is the link with the pic of sorted by table2 (ID_aneurysm)[Sorted by aneurysm_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85HVn.png)

Here is the link with the pic sorted by table1 (ID_imaging)[sorted by imaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dV3B.png)

I want to be able to display in table1 (patient_ID) all Imaging_ID information from table3 with the corresponding information of Aneurysm_ID from table2

Could you help me?

P.S: If you think about a more relevant title let me know I am a newbie in Filemaker

Comment: This question is borderline off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you are a FileMaker beginner, I would recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the portal to show all images related to the patient, you must define the portal to show records from the `Images` table.

In order to display the data from the corresponding record in the `Aneurysms` table, use either calculation fields defined in the `Images` table, or place another occurrence of the `Aneurysms` table on the graph like this:

```
Patients -< Aneurysms -< Images >- Aneurysms 2
```

and place fields from `Aneurysms 2` in the portal.

---

Note that aneurysms without images will not be shown.